# storing UTC timestamp in mysql

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

I want to store UTC timestamp in my mysql datatbase. Would storing it as a data type of `INT` be enough? Currently, the timestamp has a length of 10 digits and `INT` datatype has a limit max value of signed 2147483647. I am pretty new to `mysql` so I'm not sure what is typically done.

Comment: Why do you feel you should store a timestamp as an integer why not just store it as a timestamp?

Comment: what if you use `timestamp` data type? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html

Comment: If one of the answers helped you, would you mind marking it as an answer to give closure to this question? Thank you, @Liondancer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the built-in datatype for timestamp like so:

```
create table test (id int, ts timestamp null default current_timestamp);
insert into test (id) values (1), (2), (3);

select * from test;

Result: 
| id |                          ts |
|----|-----------------------------|
|  1 | September, 14 2015 02:48:59 |
|  2 | September, 14 2015 02:48:59 |
|  3 | September, 14 2015 02:48:59 |
```

This way you have no specific conversion to do and you can query the information with human readable dates.

Answer (score 3):

yes, you can store UTC time as int 11.

your will need to use from_unixtime() to convert it back to datatime format in sql query.

Comment: Until some time in the year 2038.

Comment: should not be afraid of 2038. in 2037 "they" certainly will do some magic about that.